# How to make two parameters dependent in tableau

Tags: filter, parameters, dependencies, tableau-api

I need to make one of my parameter filter dependent on other parameter filter. Is there any way to acheive it?

Comment: interesting question... waiting for answer from experts

Comment: There's not a way to make parameters dependent. However, if there's a possibility that the values of your parameters could come from a data source (even if it's simply an Excel file), it's very doable using filters that will change their options based on other selected filter values.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'dependent'? You could:

1. Create Parameter #1
2. Create Calculated Field #1 to reference P1
3. Create Parameter #2, uses Calculated Field #1
4. Create Calculated Field #2 to filter based on Parameter #2

While this is possible, I am struggling to find a business scenario. In most dashboards, I over-engineered to get to this solution, and ended up throwing it out after finding a simpler solution.